# How to wait for 1 minute for the speaker's silence before start Recognition

Tags: reactjs, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text

I want azure speech to text service to wait for at least 1 minute before it start recognizing the speech. Or speaker himself click on the button after he complete his speech, then azure speech to text service should start recognizing the text from the speech.

I tried below code but it does not works

```
const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
      subscriptionKey,
      serviceRegion,
    );
    const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();

    speechConfig.setProperty(
      PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_EndSilenceTimeoutMs,
      '60000',
    );

    const recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();

    console.log(new Date().toString());
    
    recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync((result) => {
      if (result.reason === ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        const recognized = result.text;
        console.log(new Date().toString());
        console.log(recognized);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer, the max value allowed in Speech_SegmentationSilenceTimeoutMs is 5000,

Here is the updated code

```
    const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
      subscriptionKey,
      serviceRegion,
    );
    const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();

    speechConfig.setProperty(
      PropertyId.Speech_SegmentationSilenceTimeoutMs,
      '5000',
    );

    const recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    console.log(new Date().toString());

    recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync((result) => {
      if (result.reason === ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        const recognized = result.text;
        console.log(new Date().toString());
}
}
```